# Multiple Domain Variations Requiring Apache Site-wide 301 Redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

So I have a website which is currently running under 4 variations:

http://www.example.com / https://www.example.com

&

http://example.com / https://example.com

I am working on a solution to have all variations redirecting to:
https://www.example.com

I have read lots about how to use an Apache domain 301 redirect to solve the http to https (there seems to be lots of formulas), however I am wondering if there is a more efficient code to have all these variations 301 redirecting to the https://www. version?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am a complete noob when it comes to server-side htaccess language etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single `301` redirect rule to get both tasks done:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add www and http -> https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Hi anubhava, thanks for your help! This looks like what i am after. Could i ask you to explain what each line does in order to educate myself moving forward?

Comment: First 2 `RewriteCond` have `OR` clause which means this rule will execute for `http://` URL or `non-www` URLs. 3rd `RewriteCond` captures part after optional `www` and in the `RewriteRule` we add both `www` and `https` in the final URL.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to https://www , you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```